# Matching values of a list in karate?

Tags: automated-tests, ui-automation, karate

while working with the html tables, I have fetched row data in form of list.
For instance: table having 5 columns out of which two columns have blank as value and remaining three have some text values there.

So the list looks like :
`["12.5"," ","22","test"," "]`
Now, while providing the same as expected list, the assertion fails in exact match and not able to accept blanks as the value for matching purpose which ideally is needed.

Sharing part of the report here:
[image]

How to make an exact match in this case having comparison of two lists. Please help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked:

```
* def response = ["12.5"," ","22","test"," "]
* match response == ["12.5"," ","22","test"," "]
```

So I have no idea what you are talking about. So please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue